# How to determine in C++ if an element in a text file is a character or numeric?

Tags: c++, integer, character, text-files

I am trying to write a code in C++ reading a text file contains a series of numerics. For example, I have this .txt file which contains the following series of numbers mixed with a character:

```
1 2 3 a 5
```

I am trying to make the code capable of recognizing numerics and characters, such as the 4th entry above (which is a character), and then report error.

What I am doing is like

```
double value;
while(in) {
  in >> value;
  if(!isdigit(value)) {
      cout << "Has non-numeric entry!" << endl;
      break;
  }
  else
      // some codes for storing the entry
}
```

However, the `isdigit` function doesn't work for text file. It seems when I am doing `in >> value`, the code will implicitly type-cast `a` into double.

Can anyone give me some suggestion?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Read `char`s instead of `double`s and you'll find `isdigit` to be much more effective.

Comment: OK. I'm figuring out where the confusion is. `in >> value;` has different behaviour depending on the type of `value`. If `value` is a `double`, it tries to read a floating point number. if `value` is an `int` it tries to read an integer. if `value` is a string, it tries to read a bunch of characters up to the next whitespace. If `value` is `MyCustomClass` you need to provide an [`operator>>` overload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading) that knows how to read a `MyCustomClass`.

Comment: if any of these `>>` overloads cannot transform what's in the stream into whatever `value` is it either halts and returns what it has managed to transform or sets an error flag in `in` and leave it to the programmer to sort out the mess.

Comment: Since you don't know what you are going to be receiving, you have to read for the lowest common denominator, characters, and transform the characters yourself.

Comment: You can use your `double` value, but instead of checking `isdigit`, you need to check whether `failbit` was set on the stream indicating invalid input (e.g. a non-digit (or `+/e-.`) matching failure) by checking `in.fail()`. This should be done after checking `in.eof() || in.bad()`. See [std::basic_ios::rdstate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdstate)

Answer (score 1):

Try reading the tokens into `string` and explicitly parsing it

```
ifstream infile("data.txt");
string token;
while (infile >> token) {
    try {
        double num = stod(token);
        cout << num << endl;
    }
    catch (invalid_argument e) {
        cerr << "Has non-numeric entry!" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Much better. Now if you get more downvotes they'll probably be because using exceptions to trap a non-exceptional event (you know there will be non-numeric characters in the input) is a fairly heavyweight solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` loop doesn't do what you think it does.
It only iterates one statement:

```
in >> value;
```

The rest of the statements are actually outside the loop.
Using curly braces for the `while` body is always recommended

Comment: I added the curly braces in my original code. Here it just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

I created a small mini script where I would be reading in a file through a standard fstream library object as I was a little unsure on what your "in" represented.

Essentially, try to read in every element as a character and check the digit function. If you're reading in elements that are not of just length 1, a few modifications would have to be made. Let me know if that's the case and I'll try to help!

```
int main() {
    std::fstream fin("detect_char.txt");
    char x;
    while (fin >> x) {
        if (!isdigit(x)) {
            std::cout << "found non-int value = " << x << '\n';
        }
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great googly moogly. Someone finally got it. +1. Mind if I fix up the formatting a little?

Comment: @user4581301 yea if it helps, surely fix it up!

Comment: @bolov im not sure what you mean? all whitespaces would be ignored through this process.

Comment: To be honest, @bolov , I had to look it up. been a long time since I used `>>` to read into a character. I think Drimik has the right of it.

Comment: Original code doesn't even compile. It contains a `break` not nested in any loop since the while body is missing braces and hence contains a single statement only: `in >> value;`. So either fix the original post, or at least up-vote my answer below which points it out.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom your answer highlights a sideshow. Yes, that's a problem, but the question is primarily about how to differentiate a number and a character in a stream, and your answer does not address this at all.

Comment: thx for the tip. Is there anyway I can do this with type `double`? With some other functions besides `isdigit`? Because I would probably do some numeric operations on these numbers.

Comment: @SJH if you read directly into a `double`, the stream will be placed into an error condition. You can test for the error, clear it and either `std::istream::ignore` until you find whitespace or... Smurf. Why am I not writing an answer? Anyway read and discard until you find whitespace and the go back to looking for `double`s.

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like the Asker's end goal is to have a `double` value for their own nefarious purposes and not simply detect the presence of garbage among the numbers, what the heck. Let's read a `double`.

```
double value;
while (in) // loop until failed even after the error handling case
{
    if (in >> value) // read a double.
    {
        std::cout << value; // printing for now. Store as you see fit
    }
    else // failed to read a double
    {
        in.clear(); // clear error
        std::string junk; 
        in >> junk; // easiest way I know of to read up to any whitepsace. 
                    // It's kinda gross if the discard is long and the string resizes
    }
}
```

## Caveat:

What this can't handle is stuff like 3.14A. This will be read as 3.14  and stop, returning the 3.14 and leave the A for the next read where it will fail to parse and then be consumed and discarded by `in >> junk;` Catching that efficiently is a bit trickier and [covered by William Lee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53112688/4581301). If the exception handling of `stod` is deemed to expensive, [use `strtod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof) and test that the `end` parameter reached the end of the string and no range errors were generated. See the example in [the linked `strtod` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof)